# Flink 1.10 Container is running beyond physical memory limits

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn, flink-streaming

I was running a `Flink` SQL job on `Yarn` cluster. Everything was fine for a couple of weeks until it encountered following error:

```
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:186)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.notifyTaskFailure(UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.notifySchedulerNgAboutInternalTaskFailure(ExecutionGraph.java:1703)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1252)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1220)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.fail(Execution.java:955)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SingleLogicalSlot.signalPayloadRelease(SingleLogicalSlot.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SingleLogicalSlot.release(SingleLogicalSlot.java:165)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotSharingManager$SingleTaskSlot.release(SlotSharingManager.java:732)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotSharingManager$MultiTaskSlot.release(SlotSharingManager.java:537)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.AllocatedSlot.releasePayload(AllocatedSlot.java:149)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPoolImpl.tryFailingAllocatedSlot(SlotPoolImpl.java:733)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotPoolImpl.failAllocation(SlotPoolImpl.java:713)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.internalFailAllocation(JobMaster.java:533)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.notifyAllocationFailure(JobMaster.java:659)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:281)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:201)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:154)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Container [pid=18272,containerID=container_e25_1603189356829_1231516_01_000002] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 8.0 GB of 8 GB physical memory used; 10.2 GB of 24 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

As you can see that I configured `8 GB` for the job. And it obviously looks like a OOM incident. But the `Grafana` metrics shows that the memory was not overflowed.

[image: TaskManager memory]

Note that the memory metric is calculated like this:

```
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_MemoryUsed
+ flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Used
+ flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_MemoryUsed
+ flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Used
```

GC looks normal.

The only abnormal metric is TaskManager Heap memory:

[image: TaskManager heap used]

```
Flink version: 1.10
Java version: 1.8
Flink on Yarn
```

Can it be solved by adding more memory?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using for StateBackend ?

Comment: I'm using RocksDB for the StateBackend. And I just found out the used Heap was going up in past 7 days, until the application crashed. It's running on Per-job mode. Parallelism: 4; Memory: 8G. I think the number of the slots was 1 as defaults. (Sorry for the late response.)

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar error,the task manager heap memory usage was on the higher side.
With Hashmap Statebackend,the default TM Managed Memory
fraction of 0.4 was being unused.So we set it to 0.05, which provisioned higher heap memory.
Or Perhaps the nature of data has changed leading to skew.

Physical Memory may be used by the other factors,such as Direct(Native) Memory configured,JVM Overhead,Memory used by GC Process,Threadstack and not just Heap Usage.
We enabled Native Memory check on Task Manager JVM and check the usage.
http://cloudsqale.com/2020/04/29/flink-1-9-off-heap-memory-on-yarn-troubleshooting-container-is-running-beyond-physical-memory-limits-errors/

As per official doc,increasing the Task Manager JVM Overhead to 0.15 seems to be helping us.
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/memory/mem_tuning/#configure-memory-for-containers

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/memory/mem_trouble/#container-memory-exceeded